# Exclude an absolute path folder in the rsync --exclude-from option?

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

My example folder layout is the following:

```
/games/scripts/myscript.sh
/games/doom/doom.sh
/games/quake/quake.sh

/books/scripts/manuscript.txt
/books/text/hamlet.txt
/books/text/shakespeare.txt
```

I want to include `/books/scripts`, but not copy `/games/scripts/`
In my rsync script, I tell it to loop over a file containing the following

- directories.txt

  ```
  /games
  /books
  ```

In my exclude file, it contains the following

- exclude.txt

  ```
  /games/scripts/
  ```

My command is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -zaxvrlog --stats \
  --exclude-from="exclude.txt" \
  --delete --rsh="/usr/bin/ssh -q" \ 
  "kevin"@"myhost.internal":"${directory}" "${directory_stripped}"
```

When it runs, neither directory has the /scripts/

I understand that rsync uses relative directories for the exclude, but I want it to run absolute if possible. I have tried formatting the rsync differently thinking it might change the behaviour, but it still ignores the `/scripts/` path on both directories

Comment: Look at the `--filter` options `--filter=-_/books/scripts` should do.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin - is there any way to include multiple filters from a file, like the exclude file rather than naming individual paths?

Comment: Yes, you can include `--fileter=...` as many times as you need.